# Toolplus in Grid

Tags: extjs, panel

I need to create a custom tool in EXT panel. Please let me know how do i render a custom image for my tool.

{
                type:'mytool',

```
            tooltip: 'This is my tool',
            handler: function(event, toolEl, panel){
            //func body

            }]
```

Comment: do you want to display a image as tooltip?

Comment: No i want to add a image in tool plus in grid, like plus,minus, collapse

Comment: i did it with css :.x-tool-mytool{ background:url('././images/img.png') no-repeat right top !important;)}

Answer (score 0):

those tools have types, for example:

```
tools:[{
    type: 'plus',
    tooltip: 'some tool',
    handler: function(event, toolEl, panel){

    }
}]
```